# Interval of current week

Tags: sql-server, date, intervals

How can I get the interval from the beginning of the current week to its end
for example

```
20210118
20210119
20210120
20210121
20210222
20210123
```

So that the check date is current without manually entering dates.

I can get start date and end date but need interval output.

```
SET DATEFIRST 4  
DECLARE @d DATETIME

SET @d = GETDATE()

SELECT
  @d ThatDate,
  DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @d)) % 7, @d) Monday,
  DATEADD(dd, 6 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @d)) % 7, @d) Sunday
```

Comment: Give us a hint - can you show us the output you expect? I don't know exactly what you mean by "need interval output." Also, is `20210222` a typo? And please spell out things like `day` instead of using [lazy shorthand like `dd`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) - you saved one character, what did you gain?

Comment: yes, you are right
20210222 it's my mistake, correct is 20210122. data must be in datetime format

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive CTE. I've got the results you posted as an example, but that's only six days. Not sure if you want to exclude Sunday or not?

```
SET DATEFIRST 4  
DECLARE @d DATETIME

SET @d = GETDATE()


;WITH cte AS(

    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @d)) % 7, @d) Dts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,Dts) Dts
    FROM cte
    WHERE Dts <= DATEADD(dd, 4 - (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @d)) % 7, @d)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
```